# sklearn: bins must be monotonically increasing or decreasing

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a Python list containing continuous values (from 0 to 1020) that I'd like to descritize in ordinal values from 0 to 5 using K-Means strategy.

I have used the new class `sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer` to perform that:

```
def descritise_kmeans(python_arr, num_bins):
    X = np.array(python_arr).reshape(-1, 1) 
    est = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=num_bins, encode='ordinal', strategy='kmeans')
    est.fit(X)  
    Xt = est.transform(X)
    return Xt
```

When running this method, I got error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_discretization.py in transform(self, X)
    262             atol = 1.e-8
    263             eps = atol + rtol * np.abs(Xt[:, jj])
--> 264             Xt[:, jj] = np.digitize(Xt[:, jj] + eps, bin_edges[jj][1:])
    265         np.clip(Xt, 0, self.n_bins_ - 1, out=Xt)
    266 

ValueError: bins must be monotonically increasing or decreasing
```

When looking closely at this, seems like `numpy.descritize` method is the one that throws the error. This seems to be a bug of Sklearn library.

When number of bins `n_bins` is 6, the error is thrown. However, when `n_bins`  is 5, it works.

Comment: Can you please provide the data which can reproduce this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem and I find my mistake in setting values for the bins. My code is simple

```
bins = np.array([0.0, .33, 66, 1])
data = [0.1, .2, .4, .5, .7, 8]
inds = np.digitize(data, bins, right=False)
```

I missed a dot before .66 and my bins were not monotonic. While it may not be the source of the problem in this question, I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

**Makeshift solution:**
Edit sklearns sourcecode with this transform function:   sklearn/preprocessing/_discretization.py
It is at line 237 as of version '0.20.2'

```
def transform(self, X):
    """Discretizes the data.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : numeric array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
        Data to be discretized.

    Returns
    -------
    Xt : numeric array-like or sparse matrix
        Data in the binned space.
    """
    check_is_fitted(self, ["bin_edges_"])

    Xt = check_array(X, copy=True, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
    n_features = self.n_bins_.shape[0]
    if Xt.shape[1] != n_features:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect number of features. Expecting {}, "
                         "received {}.".format(n_features, Xt.shape[1]))


    def ensure_monotic_increase(array):
        """ 
        add small noise to the bin_edges[i] 
        when bin_edges[i] !> bin_edges[i-1]
        """
        noise_overlay = np.zeros(array.shape)
        for i in range(1,len(array)):
            bigger = array[i]>array[i-1] 
            if bigger:
                pass
            else:
                noise_overlay[i] = abs(array[i-1] * 0.0001)
        return(array+noise_overlay)

    bin_edges = self.bin_edges_
    for jj in range(Xt.shape[1]):
        # Values which are close to a bin edge are susceptible to numeric
        # instability. Add eps to X so these values are binned correctly
        # with respect to their decimal truncation. See documentation of
        # numpy.isclose for an explanation of ``rtol`` and ``atol``.
        rtol = 1.e-5
        atol = 1.e-8
        eps = atol + rtol * np.abs(Xt[:, jj])

        old_bin_edges = bin_edges[jj][1:]

        try:
            Xt[:, jj] = np.digitize(Xt[:, jj] + eps, old_bin_edges)
        except ValueError:
            new_bin_edges = ensure_monotic_increase(old_bin_edges)
            #print(old_bin_edges)
            #print(new_bin_edges)
            try:
                Xt[:, jj] = np.digitize(Xt[:, jj] + eps, new_bin_edges)
            except:
                raise

    np.clip(Xt, 0, self.n_bins_ - 1, out=Xt)

    if self.encode == 'ordinal':
        return Xt

    return self._encoder.transform(Xt)
```

**The issue (that I encountered)**
The bin edges were too close to each other. *Possibly*, by some kind of floating point error, the prior bin edge ends up larger than the next bin edge.
When printing the edges, (uncomment the print statements in the above function), the first 2 bin edges were observably equal to each other. The printed bin_edges were:

```
[-0.1025641  -0.1025641   0.82793522]             # ValueError 
[-0.1025641  -0.10255385  0.82793522]             # After fix
[0.2075     0.2075     0.88798077]                # ValueError 
[0.2075     0.20752075 0.88798077]                # After fix
[ 0.7899066   0.7899066  24.31967669]             # ValueError 
[ 0.7899066   0.78998559 24.31967669]             # After fix
[5.47545572e-18 5.47545572e-18 2.36842105e-01]    # ValueError 
[5.47545572e-18 5.47600326e-18 2.36842105e-01]    # After fix
[5.47545572e-18 5.47545572e-18 2.82894737e-01]    # ValueError 
[5.47545572e-18 5.47600326e-18 2.82894737e-01]    # After fix
[-0.46762302 -0.46762302 -0.00969465]             # ValueError 
[-0.46762302 -0.46757626 -0.00969465]             # After fix
```